# Campy, Cheesy, Corny

Tags: adjectives, word-difference

The wiktionary defines them as:

> **campy:**
>
> Characterized by camp or kitsch, especially when deliberate or intentional.

---

> **corny:**
>
> Insipid or trite.
>   Hackneyed or excessively sentimental.

---

> **cheesy:**
>
> (informal) Overdramatic, excessively emotional or clichéd, trite, contrived.

So, there's a definite overlap between the three and I don't quite grasp the difference between them, maybe except *campy* not being linked to emotions.

Can you give me a good comparison between them, and e.g. examples when one would be applicable but the others not?

Comment: Corny and cheesy are very close, though I think that _corny_ is usually more negative than _cheesy_. But _camp_ (which I would use rather than _campy_  - I don't recognise _campy_) is quite different.

Comment: @ColinF - I agree; _campy_ can be used in a compliment, because it recognizes the cheesiness was deliberate. For example, a movie reviewer might say that one film was "dreadfully corny," but another was "delightfully campy" (or "full of delightful camp," if you prefer that).

Comment: I would expect "delightfully camp", @J.R. In my experience _camp_ is an adjective more often than a noun in this sense.

Comment: @ColinF - Interesting. I wonder if that's a AmE/BrE preference.

Comment: *Teklans tended to be the coplike authorities given responsibility for chasing them down and
breaking up their human-smuggling rings, leading to stereotypical depictions in popular culture of
Dinans as charismatic pirates and Teklans as humorless straight arrows. Or at least that had been the
case until the Sooners’ transgressions had led to the War in the Woods, in which the predominantly
Teklan armed forces had been obliged to rescue many Dinan adventurers. Depictions nowadays were
a little more nuanced and made the older ones seem **campy**.* -- Neal Stephenson, Seveneves.

Comment: (that's where I encountered it most recently, and which led me to a conclusion I don't really understand how the expressions differ.)

Comment: I also find "cheesy" is more used in a romantic context, though the usage can be more flexible.

Comment: Johnny Depp is "delightfully camp" in Pirates of the Caribbean. This web site has a selection of "cheesy and corny" jokes.http://www.quickfunnyjokes.com/cheesy.html

Comment: One fundamental difference I think I'm spotting is that 'campy' applies to creative works: movies, books, acting etc. You wouldn't say someone's business pitch was campy.

Answer (score 1):

Corny and cheesy are negative descriptions.  That is, they are bad.  But they are honest and straightforward.

Camp is subversive.  Camp subverts something good by showing you how it's bad by illustrating, for example, how corny and cheesy it can be.  To pull this off one must be convinced that the corn and cheese are deliberate.  This is usually accomplished by going to [absurd extremes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCiTAJi1yRk).